# How do I use DataReader on python to get price data for after hour trades?

Tags: finance, price, pandas-datareader

More specifically, I am trying to create a daily time series for the final price of AAPL in the after hours market. How can I do this using datareader in python? If this is not possible with datareader, is there another way to do this?

I can get the daily time series for the price of AAPL during regular market hours using pandas_datareader. But, I cannot find a way to get after hours price data.